# Powershell - possible to insert variable or character in the middle of a variable result?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to work out how to insert a variable that contains one character in the middle of a variable

For example:

```
$fullnameresult = 'John doe'
$comma = ','
write-output $full$($comma)nameresult
```

I am hoping for the output to be:

```
John,Doe
```

Apart from the obvious inserting comma into the $fullnameresult variable, is there another way of doing it? I know this might sound silly but theres a long story behind it and this is the easiest way I could think of explaining it

Comment: `$fullnameresult -replace ' ',','`

Comment: You cannot cut a variable name in half, hoping that by doing so the **content** of that variable will also be separated in two.. Do as @MathiasR.Jessen commented or try something else like `$fullnameresult -split ' ' -join ','`